# Counting objects from Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to write a little powershell script (I have no experience in Powershell scripting so was wanting to use this as a test) that loops through our svn repositories counting how many commits have been made with a comment of "Reviewed by; No-one" as this indicates an unreviewed commit.

I currently have the following

```
$repositorys = @("Path1", "path2","path3","path4")
$matches = 0
foreach ($path in $repositorys){
"Path: {0}" -f $path.tostring() 
( [xml] (svn log --xml $path)).log.logentry | Where-Object {$_.msg -imatch "(Reviewed By: (no(.*)one))" } | measure-object | format-list

}
```

This gives me the output with the count depending on how many matches it has found

```
          Count Average             Sum                 Maximum             Minimum             Property
          ----- -------             ---                 -------             -------             --------
              1
```

If I remove the measure-object then I get the  details of the SVN commit  (revision, author, message, date etc.)

Essentially what I want to be able to report is the number of un-reviewed commits and there details (so essentially a merge between the two methods described above). So I have report that looks like

Path1:

```
Number of un-reviewed commits: xx
   Revision             Author
   --------             ------- 
    x                    x
```

Can anyone enlighten me?? Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the [**Tee-Object**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet is for.

```
[xml] (svn log --xml $path)).log.logentry | 
    ? {$_.msg -imatch "(Reviewed By: (no(.*)one))" } | 
    tee -variable temp | 
    measure |
    % { "Number of un-reviewed commits: $($_.count)" }
$temp | fl
```

There's nothing here you can't do by manually breaking up the pipeline & assigning variables, but "tee" is a handy shortcut to know.

Its other common use is to write intermediate results to a file.  See 'help tee -examples' for details.

Answer (score 2):

well, in that case you'd have to output two different things. I'd suggest you save the result of the pipeline that does the work in a variable and then do something like the following:

```
$x = ( [xml] (svn log --xml $path)).log.logentry | Where-Object {$_.msg -imatch "(Reviewed By: (no(.*)one))" }

Write-Host Number of un-reviewed commits: ($x.Count)
$x | fl
```

So you just output the number and then just drop your collection from the pipeline to print it.